# Как слова из файла добавить в список

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть файл `Dictory.txt` в нем лежит что то вроде:

```
арбуз
морковь
слово
тыква
привет
пока
до свидания
ничего
```

Как прочитать все эти слова в список?

При попытках написать `mas = file.readlines` или `mas = list(file)` ничего не получилось, `print(mas)` выводит только первое слово

Я 2 дня не могу это решить пробовал сам и искал тут, но получилось так что или код для меня был сложный и я не мог его под себя подстроить или вовсе не работало как надо

Comment: Справа есть колонка "похожие". Не найдётся ли там чего?

Comment: .readlines() возвращает список.

Answer (score 1):

наверное действительно, плохо искал :)

```
with open("Dictory.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    words = [word.strip() for word in file.readlines()]
print(words)
```

результат:

```
['арбуз', 'морковь', 'слово', 'тыква', 'привет', 'пока', 'до свидания', 'ничего']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Во многих компилерах выводит пустой список, не знаю с чем связана проблема

Comment: запусти дебаг и посмотри по шагам

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('test.txt', 'r')

file_data = file.readlines()

print(file_data)
```

Есть только один минус - питон запишет в строки ещё и ентер - `\n`.

Comment: не запишет, в каждой строке есть ``\n``, потому что каждая строка им заканчивается.

Comment: @Эникейщик, как не запишет, если ```\n``` компонент строки, а значит должен иметься.

Comment: ну он и будет иметься. Только иметься изначально, а не "питон запишет".

Comment: @Эникейщик, вот так лучше?

Comment: да ничего питон туда не запишет! Этот энтер (он называется перевод строки по-правильному) там уже изначально есть.

Comment: @Эникейщик, он в переменную запишет... Я про это говорю...

Comment: Да блин. Каждая строка в файле заканчивается этим энтером. Именно этот "энтер" и делает строку отдельной строкой. Ничего питон никуда не запишет, потому что эти энтеры берутся из файла, в котором они уже есть.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143081/discussion-between-mrsvinia-and-).

Comment: тут нечего продолжать

Comment: @Эникейщик, да я случайно нажал. Не знаю куда тыкать. Я вот про что: питон читает файл, читает строчку и записывает её в список с ентером.

Comment: а, ну это да...

Answer (score 0):

Есть такое решение:

```py
with open('Dictory.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

print(lines)
```

Вывод:

```py
['арбуз', 'морковь', 'слово', 'тыква', 'привет', 'пока', 'до свидания', 'ничего']
```

Comment: Разницы с `mas = file.readlines()` быть не должно по идее, это тоже самое.